# Visual Studio 2005 Device Emulator

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, emulation, visual-studio-2005

I need to debug my software in device emulator of Visual Studio 2005. On my old computer it was configured by my colleague which no longer works here. I have newer PC now (with visual studio 2005 installed) and I do not know how to set it up.

Can somebody help me please? I have access to the old PC so I could get some files or images if it is needed. Thank you in advance.

Comment: why not use 2015/2017?

Comment: Because the application has to run on Windows 6.0 CE and second our company does not have any other license except VS 2013 which does not support the 6.0 CE as far as I know.

Comment: Windows 6? I think you need to update your OS' as well...

Comment: Sorry but I do not understand. Which OS should I update? On the old PC I have Win 7 with VS 2005 and emulator of Win 6.0 CE. On the new one I have Win 10 with VS 2005 and VS 2013. The target device is Win 6.0.

Comment: @Radim Sejk, VS2005 was really old version, actually we don't support it, and we also have no that Environment now. Two documents which shared information about how to debug applications in Windows CE Devices: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/205617/Debugging-Managed-Applications-in-Windows-CE-Devic and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb278114.aspx, if possible, you could refer to it.

Comment: In addition, in higher VS versions like VS2015/VS2017, certain old project types have been updated, for example, they support the UWP or windows phone developing or others. If you are interested in them, I think you could also get useful information from the MSDN forum: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/home?forum=wpdevelop

Comment: Yeah I know it is old (as old as my company and people in it :D) Thank you for the articles, I will look at them.

Comment: @Radim Sejk, If you get any latest information, please feel free to share it here.